# Fazer string JSON de métodos voltarem a funcionar depois de serem convertidos novamente em objeto

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-8

No escopo da classe tenho uma coleção com 2 métodos que acionam outros métodos dentro da mesma classe, que são executados na view através do clique do botão, porém eu preciso guardar essa coleção em memória:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of collectionFilter">
   <button (click)="item.action($event)">Ação criar</button> | 
   <button (click)="item.reset()">Ação resetar</button>
</ng-container>
```

Dentro da classe eu tenho esse trecho que seria a coleção:

```
this.collectionFilter = [];

let formParticipants =  {
                typeComponent: 'customMultiselect',
                additionalClasses:'appraisal-filter',
                items: this.appraisalsChecked,
                resetItems: [...this.appraisalsChecked],
                reset:() => {
                    this.appraisalsChecked = [];
                },
                selectionLimit: this.appraisalsChecked.length,
                label: this.translate.instant('PDI_PAGE.BUTTONS.FILTER.LABEL.APPRAISAL_FILTER'),
                uniqueId:'dropdownAppraisalFilter',
                action:(event) => { 
                    this.appraisalsSelectionChanges(event);
                    this.collectionFilter[this.collectionFilter.findIndex(c => c.id == 'APPRAISAL')].totalResultAction = this.totalSelected(this.appraisalsChecked);
                }
             } 

            this.collectionFilter.push( {
                id:'APPRAISAL',
                name:this.translate.instant('PDI_PAGE.FORM.LABEL.APPRAISAL'),
                typeComponent: formParticipants.typeComponent,
                data: formParticipants,
                type:removeColon(this.translate.instant('PDI_PAGE.FORM.LABEL.APPRAISAL')),
                isActive: false,
                isSelected: false,
                totalResultAction:0
            });
```

E lá dentro tem um método que converte tudo isso para um JSON, que é salvo:

```
let convertExample = JSON.stringify(this.collectionFilter):
```

E depois para ser usado, ele é uma string JSON revertida em objeto:

```
let resultExample = JSON.parse(convertExample):
this.collectionFilter = resultExample;
```

Porém, ao fazer isso, o JSON parece perder as duas funções de execução `action($event)` e `reset()`.

> Existe alguma maneira de preservar essas ações, ou uma forma de rescrever os métodos para que ele voltem a funcionar da mesma maneira antes de ser convertidos em string?

[Dúvida similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69212064/basic-stringify-question-with-call-back-function)

Answer (score -1):

Ao converter um objeto para uma string JSON usando `JSON.stringify()`, todas as suas propriedades e métodos são perdidos, pois o JSON é uma representação de dados e não tem suporte para código. Portanto, ao usar `JSON.parse()` para transformar a string de volta em um objeto, essas propriedades e métodos não são recriados.

Uma forma de contornar esse problema é criar uma classe que possa ser serializada e desserializada para e a partir de JSON sem perder suas propriedades e métodos. Para isso, basta criar um método `toJSON()` e um método estático `fromJSON()` na classe.

Por exemplo, considere a seguinte classe:

```
class MinhaClasse {
  constructor(nome, idade) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.idade = idade;
  }

  saudacao() {
    console.log(`Olá, meu nome é ${this.nome} e tenho ${this.idade} anos.`);
  }

  toJSON() {
    return {
      nome: this.nome,
      idade: this.idade,
    };
  }

  static fromJSON(json) {
    const obj = new MinhaClasse(json.nome, json.idade);
    return obj;
  }
}

const minhaInstancia = new MinhaClasse('João', 30);

console.log(minhaInstancia.toJSON()); // { nome: 'João', idade: 30 }
console.log(MinhaClasse.fromJSON({ nome: 'João', idade: 30 })); // MinhaClasse { nome: 'João', idade: 30 }

const json = JSON.stringify(minhaInstancia);
console.log(json); // {"nome":"João","idade":30}

const instanciaDeserializada = JSON.parse(json, (key, value) => {
  if (key === '') {
    return MinhaClasse.fromJSON(value);
  }
  return value;
});

console.log(instanciaDeserializada); // MinhaClasse { nome: 'João', idade: 30 }

instanciaDeserializada.saudacao(); // Olá, meu nome é João e tenho 30 anos.
```

Note que o método `toJSON()` retorna um objeto com as propriedades da classe que você deseja serializar, e o método estático `fromJSON()` recebe esse objeto como parâmetro e retorna uma nova instância da classe com essas propriedades.

Para desserializar a string, basta usar o método `JSON.parse()` e passar como segundo argumento uma função que será chamada para cada chave-valor encontrada no JSON. Essa função pode ser usada para verificar se o valor corresponde a uma chave raiz (representada por uma string vazia) e, nesse caso, desserializar o objeto usando o método estático `fromJSON()`. Caso contrário, basta retornar o valor original.

No exemplo acima, a função passada como segundo argumento de `JSON.parse()` verifica se a chave é uma string vazia (que representa a raiz do objeto) e, nesse caso, desserializa o objeto usando o método estático `fromJSON()`. Caso contrário, retorna o valor original. Dessa forma, a instância da classe é recriada com as propriedades e métodos originais preservados.

Comment: Não consegui visualizar a solução criando uma classe nova, onde estão os métodos recriados action, e reset nessa classe nova?